# "New" and "delete" in a function

Tags: c++, dll, new-operator, delete-operator

Writing a dll for file manipulation, I'm running into some issue.

To read bytes from a file via file.read I require a char* array of the desired length.
Since the length is variable, I cannot use

```
char* ret_chars[next_bytes];
```

It gives the error that next_bytes is not a constant.

Another topic here in StackOverflow says to use:

```
char* ret_chars = new char[next_bytes];
```

Creating it with "new" requires to use "delete" later though, as far as I know.

Now, how am I supposed to delete the array if the return-value of this function is supposed to be exactly this array?
Isn't it a memory leak if I don't use "delete" anywhere?

If that helps anything: This is a DLL I'll be calling from "Game Maker". Therefore I don't have the possibility to delete anything afterwards.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: What will Game Maker do with the memory afterwards?

Comment: I do not know that :/

Comment: Can I use instead the initialisation and quitting-function for the DLL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're writing a callback which will be invoked by existing code, you have to follow its rules.

Assuming that the authors of "Game Maker" aren't complete idiots, they will free the memory you return.  So you have to check the documentation to find out what function they will use to free the memory, and then you have to call the matching allocator.

In these cases, the framework usually will provide an allocation function which is specially designed for you to use to allocate a return buffer.

Another common approach is that you never return a buffer allocated by the callback.  Instead, the framework passes a buffer to your callback, and you simply fill it in.  Check the documentation for that possibility as well.

Is there no sample code for writing "Game Maker" plugins/extensions?

---

It looks like the developers are indeed complete idiots, at least when it comes to design of plugin interfaces, but they do provide [some guidance](http://gamemaker.info/en/manual/414_00_dlls).

> Note that you have to be careful with memory management. That is why I declared the resulting string global.

This implies that the Game Maker engine makes no attempt to free the returned buffer.

You too can use a global, or indeed any **variable with static storage duration** such as a function-local static variable.  `std::vector<char>` would be a good choice, because it's easy to resize.  This way, every time the function is called, the memory allocated for the previous call will be reused or freed.  So your "leak" will be limited to the amount you return at once.

```
char* somefunc( void )
{
    static std::vector<char> ret_buffer;

    ret_buffer.resize(next_bytes);
    // fill it in, blah blah
    return &ret_buffer[0];
}
// std::string and return ret_string.c_str(); is another reasonable option
```

Your script in Game Maker Language will be responsible for making a copy of that result string before it calls your function again and overwrites it.

Comment: Game Maker is not another C++ library but a Games developing tool (with its own language) which allows to make calls to a DLL for extending its functions. Thing is i don't know whether it automatically deletes the char*.

Comment: @DragonGamer: I can pretty much assure you it will not use your C++ version's `delete[]`, which is what matches `new[]`.  But it should use some deallocation function.

Comment: Okey, thank you! But what do I have to include for "vector"? And how can I fill in the bytes via .read from an fstream into that array now? The function requires a char* array.

Comment: @DragonGamer: `#include <vector>`, and you can do `stream.read(&ret_buffer[0], next_bytes)` since vector contents are contiguous

Comment: @BenVoigt: Another possibility is that you allocate memory, make a call, _it copies the memory_ and after the function you free your own.   Kind of like the `const char*` constructor for `std::string`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's not really a new case; it falls into the category of "framework usually will provide an allocation function which is specially designed for you to use to allocate a return buffer". Initialization is a common feature of buffer allocation functions.  See for example [`SysAllocString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx)

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, I mean an API where you can use any arbitrary allocation function because _you're_ the one who cleans it up.  You can use `malloc` or `new` or stack based, and the API could care less.

Comment: @MooingDuck: We're not discussing what functions you use internally to help compute the data.  We're talking about constructing the buffer that gets returned.  Are you not talking about a function which you pass data, and it returns some sort of handle to a newly allocated buffer which has been initialized with that data, so you can return that buffer back to your caller, who knows how to deal with that particular kind of buffer?

Comment: @MooingDuck: There really are only two cases that make sense, and my answer mentioned them both.  (1) The caller provided a buffer which you fill in (possibly using some helper function) or (2) You call an allocator function that allocates (and possibly initializes) whatever type of buffer your caller expects to deallocate.

Answer (score 1):

The `new char[ n ]` trick works with a runtime value, and yes - you need to delete[] the array when you're done with it or it leaks.

If you are unable to change how "Game Maker" (whatever that is) works, then the memory will be leaked.

If you can change "Game Maker" to do the right thing, then *it* must manage the lifetime of the returned array.

That's the real problem here - the DLL code can't know when it's no longer needed, so the *calling* code needs to delete it when it's done, but the calling code cannot delete it directly - it must call back to the DLL to delete it, since it was the DLL's memory manager that allocated it in the first place.

Since you say the return value *must* be a char[], you therefore need to export a second function from your DLL that takes the char[], and calls delete[] on it. The calling code can then call that function when it's finished with the array returned previously.

Comment: *"The new char[ n ] trick"* - it's not a trick, it's a standard way to allocate dynamic memory.

Comment: @icepack: "Standard" from a source-code perspective only.  The metadata associated with that allocation is by no means standard, so you can't mix `new char[n]` in one DLL/compiler/library version with `delete[]` in another.

Answer (score 1):

Use `vector <char *>` (or `vector <char>` depending on which you really want - the question isn't entirely clear), that way, you don't need to delete anything.

You can not use `new` inside a function, without calling delete, or your application will be leaking memory (which is a bad thing, because EVENTUALLY, you'll have no memory left). There is no EASY solution for this, that doesn't have some relatively strict restrictions in some way or another.

Comment: Does not conisder the fact he wants to return the array.

Comment: Where do the pointers come from that you're going to put into the vector?  Did you mean `std::vector<char>`?  This won't let him return anything to his caller, since the memory will already be gone, cleaned up automatically before his function returns.

Comment: First line in OP's post: 
char* ret_chars[next_bytes];

Comment: And next line, `char* ret_chars = new char[next_bytes];`  The question is somewhat confusing, but from the rest of the question it seems he is returning an array of `char` via `char*`, and not an array of `char*`.

Comment: @NeilKirk: No, it doesn't, my second statement explains that if you REALLY need to return an array of char (* ??), then it's not an easy solution.

Comment: Or worse than leaking, you return memory gotten from the `::operator new()` allocator, and the framework tries to pass it to `HeapFree` (or the moral equivalent), and you don't just get a slow leak, you get heap corruption which causes a crash in unrelated code for which you have no debug information.

Comment: I require to return simply an array of chars. Like a string.

Comment: And is this function called once or many times, and are you supposed to return the same string every time, or different strings.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use `new char[];` you can't use `delete`, but you have to use `delete []`.

But like you said, if you use `new []` in this function without using `delete []` at the end your program will be leaking.

<del>If you want a kind of garbage collection, you can use the *smart ptr* now in the standard c++ library.

I think a `shared_ptr` would be good to achieve what you want.

> **Shared ptr** : Manages the storage of a pointer, providing a limited garbage-collection facility, possibly sharing that management with other objects.

Here is some documentation about it : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/</del>

Comment: actually, `shared_ptr` is terrible for passing buffers across DLL boundaries

Comment: @BenVoigt It can be a solution even if I am ok with your argument. But it is one of the solution. If not, he has to ask the developers (*in the function documentation*) using his DLL to free the memory after using this function...

Comment: The other module can't use `delete[]` either.  These are C++ features that other languages don't know about, and aren't even compatible across different compiler versions.

Answer (score 0):

The first code sample you quoted allocates memory on the stack.
The second code sample you quote allocates memory on the heap. (Two totally different concepts).

If you are returning the array, then the function allocating the memory does not free it. It is up to the caller to delete the memory. If the caller forgets, then yes, it is a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning a char pointer, which it looks as though you are, then you can simply call delete on that pointer.

Example:

```
char * getString()
{
    char* ret_chars = new char[next_bytes];
    strcpy(ret_chars, "Hello world")
    return ret_chars
}

void displayChars()
{
    char* chars = getString()
    cout << chars
    delete [] chars
}
```

Just be sure to deallocate (delete) all allocated (new'd) pointers or else you'll have memory leaks where the memory is allocated and then not collected after runtime and becomes unusable. A quick and dirty way to glance through and see if you've deallocated all allocated space to count your new's and count your deletes, and they should be 1-to-1 unless some appear in condition or looped blocks.

Comment: You must use delete[]

Comment: That#s a way I thought at, but like I said, Game Maker (which is a  games developing too using only a scripting language --> no memmory manipulation) doesn't allow me to directly delete the char*..

Comment: Oh I wasn't picking up on that, my bad. This tool allows you to use new but not delete? That's odd :/

Comment: @jon.kerlinger: It's not that the tool doesn't allow him to use `delete` (or `delete[]`), it's that returning already-deleted memory isn't a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll jump in as well.

If the Game Maker doesn't explicitly say it will delete this memory, then you should check to see just how big a buffer it wants and pass in a static buffer of that size instead.  This avoids all sorts of nastiness relating to cross dll versioning issues with memory management.  There has to be some documentation on this in their code or their API and I strongly suggest you find and read it.  Game Maker is a pretty large and well known API so Google should work for info if you don't have the docs yourself.